# Maximum number of concurrent notebooks

Tags: notebooks, kernel, kernel-startup

I am running MMA v13.2 on Windows 10, x86.

If I open two different notebooks, everything is fine.

Try opening a third and it displays

[image]

Of course, the operation fails because the software is already registered.

Upon contacting Wolfram, they said you can run a max of two.

I could have sworn I have run more than three notebooks in previous versions of MMA.

Am I remembering this wrong?

Comment: It depends on how you open them. If you open one, then use the Open selection in the file menu for the open notebook, you open the second/third in the same session/process. On the other hand, if you open it by say, double-clicking, you may end up launching a second independent process running Mathematica, which consumes another one of your available licenses (2 in your case). Try opening directly from the file menu and see if that helps.